# How can I configure hadoop mapreduce so that the log of my mapreduce class can output to a file?

Tags: log4j, hadoop, mapreduce

I modified the $HADOOP_HOME/conf/log4j.properies
But it is not working as what I expect.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have other `log4j.properties` files in your classpath. A problem with log4j is that the only the last `log4j.properties` it reads from the classpath will be actually used. So if you have other `log4j.properties` files in the classpath, then one of those might be getting picked up. Try to merge all these `log4j.properties` files and it should work.

Also please post the content of the `log4j.properties` files if you can. There can be a problem there as well.